# Ignore autolayout for hidden uilabel

Tags: uilabel, hidden, autolayout

I've got the following situation:

1. I'm using autolayout
2. I've a `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UILabel` for an information text. Underneath this `UILabel` are other UI elements like the `uilabel` "Price changes in" (see second picture) and other elements like a button (not shown in the picture)
3. Since the information text `uilabel` is dynamic in height, the elements underneath are vertically moved down according to the height of the information text label.
4. In the first picture you can see a horizontal line. This horizontal line moves vertically down if the height of the information label grows. The "Price changes in" label is vertically aligned according to the position of this horizontal line.

This works fine. If the information text grows the other elements are moved down as wished.

[image]

Now my problem: Sometimes the information label and the horizontal seperator needs to be hidden since there is no information text. Unfortuneatly the elements underneath the uilabel are still moved down by the height of the label although it is hidden. See the right side of my picture. The elements should be moved up by the amount marked by the red vertical bar.

How can I tell the elements "Price changes in" and so on that it should be moved upwards if the information label and the "Demands" label are hidden.

[image]

Update:

I now added two NSLayoutContstraints to my code and connected them to the created constraints in the storyboard (Have a look at the third picture)

[image]

Okay here is an explanation: I got two NSLayoutConstraints 1rst: horizontalSeparatorContstraint connects the "Price Changes in" label with the first horizontal separator UIImageView. I set the value to 4 units such that if "Demands" and "Special Requests Label" are hidden this constraint should come into effect and "Price changes in" label is moved upwards.
The second constraint: demandsLabelContstraint - this one describes the disired space in between the second horizontal UIImageView and the "Price changes in" label. The gap should be of 4 units. And this constraint should be "acitve" if the special requests text is available.

Here is some new code:

```
if( tour.specialRequests.length > 0 ) {
    [demandsLabelContstraint setPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh];
    [horizontalSeparatorContstraint setPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow];

    self.demandsLeftLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"GenericTour_Demands", @"");
    self.demandsRightLabel.text = tour.specialRequests;

    demandsLeftLabel.hidden = NO;
    demandsRightLabel.hidden = NO;
    horizontalSeparator.hidden = NO;
} else {
    [demandsLabelContstraint setPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow];
    [horizontalSeparatorContstraint setPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh];

    horizontalSeparator.hidden = YES;
    demandsRightLabel.hidden = YES;
    demandsLeftLabel.hidden = YES;
}
```

From the code you can see: My idea is to switch priorities for each situation. If the special request text is available, then the corresponding NSLayoutContraints is triggered by setting the priority.

My intention or understanding of Autolayout is, that by changing the priorities I can switch between them. But this seems not to be the case.

So how should I resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to add and remove constraints programmatically even the constraints created in Interface Builder if you add an `IBOutlet`.

So you can add an `IBOutlet` for the constraints related to information label and horizontal separator then when they are hidden, you can remove those constraints and put them back when the labels are shown again.

You would then also add a new constraint that links the Price Changes label to the horizontal separator at the top whenever the information label is hidden so that the Price Changes label will be connected correctly

There was a video in WWDC 2012 explaining how to do things like this, I think it was Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout